# Date time day/month (02/12)

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, string-formatting

This seems like something I should be able to find on Google but I'm not having much look.

I'd like to format a date as day/month. Only thing I've found it {0:M} which displays the information I want however the month written out like December rather than "12". I need to use 02/12  if possible due to space restrictions.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could try the following [format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx):

```
{0:dd/MM}
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you simply tried:

```
myDateTime.ToString(@"dd/MM");
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure its ignoring your local computer regional settings ?

What happens if you do:

```
Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString("M", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")));
```